# Trouble with an assignment involving 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on an assignment involving arrays. It is due today and my professor has not gotten back to me because it is Easter so help would really be appreciated.

The trouble I am having is with 2D arrays and printing. I have checked other questions on stack overflow that are similar and have attempted to apply them to my own but I am still not quite getting it.

What I need to do is print my array, hands, into console. I have used for loops as well as enhanced for loops outside of my deal cards for loop in an attempt to get it to work but to no avail.

```
package pokerapp;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PokerApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Poker App");
        System.out.println();

        //scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "y";

        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        //create a deck
        Deck myDeck = new Deck();

        //shuffle cards
        myDeck.shuffleCards();
        String[][] hands = new String[4][5];

        //deal cards
        int i = 0;
        for(int k=0;k<5;k++){
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
                hands[j][i] = myDeck.dealCard(i);
            }
            System.out.println("Hand " + hands + ": ");
        }

        //print 5 hands with one hand on each line
        //four cards per hand
        /* output should look something like this:
        Hand 1: H4, C5, S7, H5
        Hand 2: H3, C3, S10, S11
        ...
        */





        //ask if user wants to continue
        System.out.println("Would you like to continue? Y/N?");
        choice = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
       }
    } 
}
```

and below is my deck class just in cause.

```
public class Deck {
    private String[] suites = {"H","D","C","S"};
    private String[] cards = new String[52];

    public Deck() {
        //create deck of cards
        int index = 0;
        //loop through the suite
        for(String suite: suites){
            //generate the ace through king
            for(int j = 1; j<14;j++){
                cards[index] = suite + j;
                index++;
            } //end of ace through king
        }//end of suites
    }//end of constructor

    public void printCardArray(){
        int index = 0;

        for(String suite : suites){
            for(int j =0; j<13;j++){
                System.out.print(cards[index] + " ");
                index++;
            }
        }
    }//end of print card array

    public void shuffleCards(){
        //execute random number 100 times
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            String savedCard = "";
            int variant = ((int)(Math.random()*50)) + 1;
            for (int j = 0; j <  cards.length; j++){
               if (j + variant < cards.length){
                   savedCard = cards[j];
                   cards[j] = cards[j + variant];
                   cards[j + variant] = savedCard;
               } 
            }
        }
    }//end of shuffleCards

    public String dealCard(int index){
        return cards[index];
    } 
}
```

Comment: Did you try two nested for loop? it would fit there

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but if there are 5 hands with 4 cards each, shouldn't this: `String[][] hands = new String[4][5];` rather be `String[][] hands = new String[5][4];` this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking from original code

```
for(int k=0;k<5;k++){

    System.out.print("Hand " + k + ": ");

    for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
        hands[j][k] = myDeck.dealCard(k);
        System.out.print(hands[j][k]);

        if(j != 3) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

You can get

```
    Hand 1: H4, C5, S7, H5
    Hand 2: H3, C3, S10, S11
```

with this. But if only `hands[j][k] = myDeck.dealCard(k);` returns `H4, C5, S7, H5`

Comment: Thank you very much! That has fixed everything! I believe the issue I was having was making my print loop separate from my deal card loop. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome my friend, could you accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

> What I need to do is print my array, hands, into console.

there are many ways in which to print arrays, it just depends how you want the output to be displayed.

you can print your array like so:

```
for (String[] array : hands) {
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

or this way:

```
for (String[] array : hands) {
   for (String str : array) {
       System.out.println(str);
   }
}
```

another way:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(hands));
```

Comment: That is what I had originally used but I was not sure how to get it to output my information in the way I intend. I need to my output to be like what I have shown as an example in the comments but the suggest ways in the other stack overflow questions were not working.

Comment: Cody, what's missing? The `Hand 1:`, `Hand 2:` part? If so, just introduce a counter, `int i` and add `"Hand " + Integer.toString(i++)` at the beginning of your `println()`.

Comment: Cody then the nested for each is what you're looking for, just create a counter as @domdom has suggested.

Comment: @CodyMarshall it is up to you to sort your program out, you wanted help on printing arrays not debugging the entire program. I'd suggest you go over your assignment again and see why it is displaying null values.

Comment: Yes, it appears I am having issue with my arrays more than my output now. I have implemented the loops and they all have worked (they had not earlier when I had typed, must've been an error in my code). My output is just horrendous, must've messed up in my deal card somewhere. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Maybe you should've included an example of what your current output looks like so we can compare that to the expected output you showed us.

Comment: @domdom it seems OPs problem is no longer the output but rather why he is getting 'null' values printed out.

Comment: @domdom the issue I was having was having my print loop separate from my dealcard loop. Gürtuğ Güngör noticed this when he posted his response.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into `Arrays.deepToString()`[Class Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[]))